# Placing nodes such that node pairs are as close together as possible

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I can't even start to think up a solution to this problem...

I need to place a set of N nodes into certain positions. Each node has a list of other nodes it must be paired with, and the goal is to find the configuration with the shortest total distance between paired nodes.

As an example, I have 4 possible locations for office buildings in a city... I need to build 3 office buildings A, B, and C. However, A frequently delivers things to B, and B frequently delivers things to C. So where do I place the offices such that the delivery time is minimized.

Anyone have any ideas? It's a pretty interesting problem to tackle but I was hoping there might be an existing algorithm. Also, ideally, I'd like to be able to disallow certain nodes in certain locations, like office B can't be in position 2.

Comment: How many buildings, locations and restrictions of the type you suggested? Knowing the limits is essential to design an algorithm for the problem or to figure that it's unfeasible and needs an approximative solution. For example, I might suggest a `O(2^(2n))` algorithm, but that would be completely useless if you had more than 16 or so buildings.

Comment: Realistically, O(n^2) or less. I mean, I can brute-force the entire solution space in O(2^n) very easily... My testing requirements have about 35 nodes being placed in about 50 positions, but it's for a userspace app that could easily have hundreds of nodes in hundreds of positions.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's NP-hard, so you can only hope for an approximative solution in that case. `O(2^n)` is actually already a very sophisticated algorithm (I can only think of `O(2^(2n))`)

Comment: O(2^(2n)) is just O(2^n)... Which I'd still like to see your implementation, just pointing out that you are supposed to ignore the coefficient on complexity notation. What are you thinking of as a solution?

Comment: No, `O(2^(2n))` is not "just O(2^n)", it's factor 2^n slower and by no means does O-notation allow you to drop 2^n factors, otherwise `O(2^n) = O(1)` It's DP over bitmasks of assigned nodes and locations and I think the complexity is more like `O(2^(2n) * n)`, but I thought you came up with something better already?

Comment: Well what I'm saying is that you should try to find a good approximation scheme :)